# How fast would one have to move to achieve permanent lunar day by perpetually moving along with the solar terminator?

Tags: the-moon, colonization, calculation

This comment got posted and I did not understand it.

> [for those interested, one rod per moonhour is about a quarter furlong per fortnight.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39811/how-long-is-a-day-on-the-moon/39855#comment128993_39855)

If I [googled correctly](https://www.google.com/search?q=quarter+furlong+per+fortnight&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS755US755&oq=quarter+furlong+per+fortnight&aqs=chrome..69i57j6.1424j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and jumped to the right conclusions...

The [terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(solar)) on the Moon moves at about 9.3 miles per hour (14.9 $\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}$).

Which means you could easily drive around the Moon at the equator and always stay in day or night (your choice).  At lunar noon, drive 20mph for 4 hours, stop for 4 hours, and it would be lunar noon again.

How fast, on average, would you need to advance at the lunar equator to stay in eternal daylight?

Comment: See the short story "A Walk in the Sun" by Geoffrey Landis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Walk_in_the_Sun_(short_story)

Comment: @MarkFoskey walking on the Moon in a space suit with 15.4 km/h for 30 days continously is impossible anyway. Far away from the lunar equator the walking speed may be possible for some hours but not for many days.

Comment: A single circumnavigation beginning at local sunrise and arriving at local sunset could go slower. A lot of rough terrain - better have a course well mapped out.

Comment: @Uwe Landis did a good job of making it seem believable. Ken Fabian's observation I think is key, along with an assumption of good luck on the part of the character. But it was too relevant a story not to mention.

Comment: So the question is "if night moves at 14.9 kph, at which speed should I walk to stay in the night?"  ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the diameter 3476 km and the Moon solar day of 29.53 Earth days I calculated a speed of 15.4 km/h for the day night line at the Moon equator.

$$\frac{3476 km*π} {29.53*24 h} = 15.4 km/h = 4.28 m/s$$

That is the necessary average speed at the lunar equator to stay in eternal day light.

- A rod is 5.0292 m, so a rod per moon-hour is 0.0473 mm/s
- A furlong is 201.168 m, so a furlong per fortnight is 0.598 m/h or 0.1663 mm/s
- The ratio is then 0.0473/0.1663 or about 0.284

Answer (score 4):

A more generic answer could be:

Angular speed (constant in any point on surface) is $2\pi$ radians every $29.53 \cdot 24$ hours, which gives $0.00443 \frac{\text{rad}}{\text{h}}$.

Linear speed depend on local distance from rotation axis, which is $r \cdot cos(latitude)$.

Hence linear speed in any point on Moon surface is:

$$v = 0.00443 \cdot r \cdot cos(latitude)\ \left[\frac{\text{rad} \cdot \text{km}}{\text{h}}\right]$$

Of course for $latitude=0°$ it becomes just $0.0443 \cdot r = 0.00443 \cdot 3476 = 15.4  \frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}$.

The "standard walk speed" is around 3 km/h:

$$3 = 0.00443 \cdot 3476 \cdot cos(latitude)$$

$$ \implies latitude = arccos\left(\frac{3}{0.00443 \cdot 3476}\right) = 78.8°$$

But Sun would be vety low over the horizon, hence may be covered by craters' rims.