# Estimate of how fast will the Starship/Super Heavy be moving 5 and 10 seconds after liftoff?

Tags: falcon-heavy, saturn-v, spacex-starship, ascent

I am wanting to make a comparison of the expected initial seconds of the ascent of the Starship/Super Heavy compared to the similar time of the Saturn V ascent.

If [this chart](https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/weekly/8Page2.pdf) (from a NASA space math document) of the Saturn V Rocket Launch Speed and Height is correct, the Saturn V was initially moving at a pedestrian rate and was only at highway speeds after 10 seconds.

[image: Saturn V Time/Altitude/Speed chart]

Is there an estimate of how fast the [Starship/Super Heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) would be moving 5 and 10 seconds after liftoff?

Comment: Probably similar. If your thrust to weight ratio at liftoff is more than about 1.2, it means you didn’t bring enough fuel.

Comment: The speed after the first second was 3 m/s or 10.8 km/h, faster than a pedestrian. But initial speed was 0.

Answer (score 3):

[Teslerati's September 2019 article](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-ceo-elon-musk-debuts-starships-new-super-heavy-booster-design/) states a T/W ration of 1.5 is desirable. Calculating an *estimated* table for the first few seconds of flight is trival, as one can assume the mass is constant (it isn't), and the direction is straight up

[image: Approximate time/altitude/speed graph for a 1.5 T/W rocket]

Comment: Should I assume the units are in m/s?

Comment: They are @Bob516 - I could redo it in furlongs per minute if you would prefer?

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39858/12102

Comment: "Calculating an estimated table for the first few seconds of flight is trivial."  Is it simply F=ma?  If it is, I should've realized it myself.

Comment: Over the flight, @Bob516, the thrust increases (until it is throttled down), the mass decreases, gravity drag decreases, aerodynamic drag ... varies...  - but for the first few seconds of a typical orbital launch vehicle those values are negligible

Comment: oops, it was a link off the OP's Wikipedia link @uhoh, good catch

Comment: I've asked [why 1.5:1 TWR is desirable for a reusable launcher](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40681/195).